# Why do I get unresolved reference in setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have this code:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    fun bindItem(items: Item) {
        itemView.name.text = items.name
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(items.image).into(itemView.image)

        view.setOnClickListener {
            view.context.startActivity(view.context.intentFor<DetailsActivity>("image" to items.image, "name" to items.name))
        }
    }
}
```

Which keeps giving me an error that shows unsolved reference: view.
How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Replace `view` with `itemView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you don't keep any reference to this `view` inside your class, what you do in `Java` terms is just `super(view)` call. You can get an access to the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder#itemView` field instead:

```
fun bindItem(items: Item) {
    itemView.name.text = items.name
    Glide.with(itemView.context).load(items.image).into(itemView.image)

    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        itemView.context.startActivity(itemView.context.intentFor<DetailsActivity>("image" to items.image, "name" to items.name))
    }
}
```